# using variables in for loops using strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

So my issue is instead of writing

rooms == "south" or "South" or "s" or "S":

to get all the users inputs I would like to create a variable to
replace all the extra souths that way I wont have to repeat the steps

Tried looking it up couldn't find anything
also tried putting it in the function with multiple things.
Thanks for the help guys first time using stack overflow

```
user = input("> ")

south = ("South" or "s" or "S" or "south")

   def bedroom():
       print(f"{user} looks around and there is 3 doors in the 
       room.")
       print("Do i take the South, East or West room?")
       rooms = input("> ")
           if rooms == south:
               print("You are now in the living room.")
               living_room()
           elif rooms == "East":
               print("You have entered the TREASURE ROOM!!!")
               treasure_room()
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't useful Python syntax:

```
south = ("South" or "s" or "S" or "south")
```

It simply sets `south` to `"South"`.  How about we control the letter case and test for membership in a set:

```
EAST = {'east', 'e'}
SOUTH = {'south', 's'}

def bedroom():
    print(f"{user} looks around and there are 3 doors in the room.")
    print("Do I take the South, East or West room?")

    room = input("> ").lower()

    if room in SOUTH:
        print("You are now in the living room.")
        living_room()
    elif room in EAST:
        print("You have entered the TREASURE ROOM!")
        treasure_room()

user = input("> ")
```

Comment: Thanks again sorry I kept adding comments and deleting them figured it out you put in instead of == ill look up why that is thank you

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, just use upper() and lower() functions to standardize what the user inputs. Then you create a list of possible acceptable answers. If any can be found (e.g. south, sou, s... feel free to specify whatever), then adopt 'south' as the answer and keep coding the way you were doing.
I can see there are several ways to do it, some easier but less elegant. This is how I would do it at least...